# how to change vlc's input to a fifo

Tags: pipe, pipeline, vlc, fifo, mkfifo

I have a program that open a video.m4v and send it to a fifo.
I want to play this video through fifo using vlc but i can't and of course
I'm new to vlc

this is my program which open the video.m4v and send it to a fifo:

```
int main(){
    char massage[2048];
    char testPipe[256];
    FILE*  sourcefile = fopen("safe.mp4", "rb");
    sprintf(testPipe, "/home/milliam/pipe");
    mkfifo( testPipe, 0777);
    int saveErr = 0;
    FILE* des = fopen(testPipe,"wb");
    saveErr = errno;
    printf(" %s\n",strerror(saveErr));
    int numOfByte = 1;
    int result =0;
    while(numOfByte){
        numOfByte = fread(massage,1, 2000,sourcefile);
        result = fwrite(massage, 1, 2000, des);
        memset(massage,0,2047);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i tested the above program and understood it works fine(i.e. open a fifo and write data to it correctly)

Now i want to open the pipe using vlc:

```
~$ vlc fd://pipe
```

this doesn't work and give me below error:

```
core debug: no access modules matched
core error: open of `fd://pipe' failed
```

but when i try:

```
ffmpeg -i pipe -f asf - | vlc -
```

then vlc play video normally.

how i can make vlc to play video through pipe without using ffmpeg?

*I think i need to config vlm.conf but I even didn't know where is it and how to config it?

Answer (score 1):

`mkfifo /tmp/pipe p
vlc /tmp/pipe
cat /tmp/video.avi > /tmp/pipe`

Works here like a charm

Comment: thank you for your respond.
i tested it and worked fine but it need to be pressed play key too in vlc.